# print all numbers greater than 4 in a single column

Tags: r

I have a data with some numbers in a column named radon. I want to find all numbers bigger than 4 and count total.

I do this:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(data))
{
    if(data$radon[i]>=4)
    {
        data$radon[i]
    }
}
```

but is not working.
how can i changed it?

Comment: There are infinitely many numbers that are greater than 4.  I don't think you want to try to print all of them.

Comment: Although if you want to.... `x=5;while(x>4){cat(paste(x,"\n"));x=x+1;}`

Comment: the number is in a list, i can read from a data. totaly are 1003 numbers, so why not i can't print?

Comment: I was going to post a comment similar to @JackManey but decided I'd edit this to mean what (I think) you really meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
data$radon[data$radon>4]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wnat the count of data$radon greater than 4 use this code:

```
sum(data$radon>4, na.rm=TRUE)  
 # because TRUE will be coerced to 1 and the na.rm removes NAs
```